# Python3.4: Check if every element in a matrix is in another array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix, compare, checksum

I've tried to find an answer to this problem for a whole day without success, so I hope I can get an answer quickly. I have for example a 3x3 matrix with different numbers, and I want to check if the numbers are in another array.

For example we have the matrix:

```
a=([7,8,10],
   [4,2,2],
   [12,10,10])
```

And we want to test if all the elements in there are elements in this array:

```
g = [-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]
```

This one will return False because of the 8 in the top row.

I have programmed this code so far.

```
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(col):
                print(a[i][j])
                if matf[i][j] in g:
                    #Dont know what to do here
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
```

Hope you guys can help

Comment: Btw matf = to the matrix a

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using a `return` statement within the `if` case. This means that after the initial value is checked, the function will `return` out of the function. Instead, use a `continue`.

```
       for i in range(rows):
             for j in range(col):
                 print(a[i][j])
                 if matf[i][j] in g:
                     continue
                 else:
                     return False
       return True
```

Comment: I've tried and for some reason it goes False. Does it have something to do with the matrix being a csv file converted into list.

Comment: @MartinMansour Quick question, why are you printing a[i][j], but then comparing to matf[i][j]. Without more context as to what these two things are, I can't help you. When you print is it showing the value that you expect it to be?